# I have written a django query but need specific user information of particular date

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Models:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1,related_name='Employee')
    eid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    salary = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default=1)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50 ,null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=60)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.first_name  + '_' +  self.user.last_name


class Attendance(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1,related_name='Attendance')
    attendance_date = models.DateField(null=True)
    in_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
    out_time = models.TimeField(null=True ,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee) + '-' +  str(self.attendance_date)


class Breaks(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    break_in = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    break_out = models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    attendance =models.ForeignKey(Attendance, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1,related_name='Breaks')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.employee) + '-' + str(self.break_in) + '-' + str(self.break_out)

def detail_attendance(request):
    attendance_list = Attendance.objects.filter(employee__user_id=request.user.id)
    counter = Counter()
    return render(request, 'employee/detail_attendance.html', {'attendance_list': attendance_list, 'counter': counter})



def detail_break(request):
    break_list=Breaks.objects.filter(employee__user_id=request.user.id )
    return render(request, 'employee/detail_break.html', {'break_list': break_list})
```

I have created a function above for detail breaks. I am getting specific user data, but it is giving me the previous data as well. So I need the data for specific date for example in my attendance models I adding attendance of each user.

Please let me know what should I change in detail break.

Comment: From which specific date do you want to filter, can you elaborate? Its not clear.

Comment: for example i have marked attendance of user on date 28/11/2022 and i want to filter the breaks on user on same date, but when i am writing the above query it is showing me the breaks of multiple days not of specific date.

Comment: But in your `Breaks` model there is no DateField, it has two TimeField(s)

Comment: In your `Attendance` model you have `DateField` as `attendance_date`. You need to be specific from which model do you want to filter date?

Comment: but in fourth row i am inheriting from attendance model , does it work by this way or should i add the datefield

Comment: Do you want to filter those breaks which have attendance date as `28/11/22` means today's date as you mentioned above?

Comment: yes it worked but but if i want to check the previous day before breaks and of different date it is showing the data of current date only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249946/discussion-between-sunderam-dubey-and-nishant-sharma).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Queryset:

```py
from django.db.models import Q
from datetime import date


Breaks.objects.filter(
    Q(employee__user=request.user) & 
    Q(attendance__attendance_date=date.today())
)
```

Or:

```py
Breaks.objects.filter(
    Q(employee__user=request.user) & 
    Q(attendance__attendance_date="2022-11-28")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Breaks.objects.filter(date__range=["2011-01-01", "2011-01-31"])
```

Or if you are just trying to filter month wise:

```
Breaks.objects.filter(date__year='2011', 
                  date__month='01')
```

Please reply to this message ,If it doesn't work.